# C# WPF ListBox to string

Tags: c#, wpf, string, listbox

How can I pass a ListBox content to a string (array of strings?).
I need to get a similar format of data:

```
Value1
Value2
Value3
```

Where each Value is a separate ListBox item.

EDITED:
I wasn't too accurate with my question. I want to send desired list of values as an e-mail through my WPF application, unfortunately values are sent in one line. Even use of /n is not helping. What can I do to change appearance to list instead of string?

Answer (score 1):

Simple one line solution:

```
List<string> items = ListBox1.Items.Cast<ListBoxItem>().Select(p=> p.Content as string).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single string value instead of an array to store the result as follows:

```
string emailData=string.Empty;
//get each item's text & append emailData.
foreach(var item in listBox1.Items)
 {
     string itemData=((ContentControl)item).Content.ToString();
     emailData = emailData +itemData+"\n";
 }
//Call the method that writes the data to email, remember to use Trim() while using emailData.
WriteToEmail(emailData.Trim());
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public string[] get()
{
    string[] arr = new string[listBox1.Items.Count];
    for (int i = 0; i < listBox1.Items.Count; i++)
    {
        arr[i] = listBox1.Items[i].ToString();
    }
    return arr;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
//lb is the Listbox; array is a string[]
lb.ItemsSource= array;
```